# Blender always crashing when applying hair particle system with a cylinder as the object

Tags: modifiers, particles

Blender crashes whenever i try to apply a cylinder to a hair system particle, i don't know what is going wrong but if i change the object to a lamp it works well. I've tried reducing the number of particles as low as possible but the problem still persists, even when i reduced it to 2.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If any application crashed and it is reproducible then it is a bug and should be reported to the developers.

Comment: @ Duarte Farrajota Ramos But if i reduce the number of particles to only 1 it doesn't crash.

Comment: I understand, but that makes no difference

Comment: @BluRe.CN otherwise, share the .blend through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (upload the file, then edit the question and add the given link) so we can try the same on your exact setup. How much ram memory has your pc?

Comment: Thank you all for responding. However, it appears to be a bug as Duarte Farrajota Ramos suggested, so i downgraded blender to a previous version and everything works fine now.